# FastAPI: Implementing Middleware in FastAPI to Check Superuser Status via JWT from External Service

Tags: authentication, jwt, authorization, fastapi, middleware

I have two interconnected services in my system. The first one, Service A, is responsible for content management and has two routers: one for core management and another for frontend interactions. The second service, Service B, handles authentication and authorization using JWT tokens. When a user logs in, Service B provides a bearer token, and user accounts are classified into two types: normal users and superusers, with superusers having the is_superuser field set to True in the JWT payload.

I'm currently faced with the task of creating a middleware within Service A, using FastAPI, to ascertain whether incoming requests—specifically those directed at the core management router—are originating from superusers. This requires the middleware to communicate with Service B to validate the JWT token and determine the user's superuser status.

I've made initial attempts to devise the middleware using FastAPI, but I've encountered difficulties in integrating it with Service B to validate JWTs and extract superuser status. I expected the process to involve validating the JWT with Service B's authentication system and subsequently accessing the JWT payload to determine if the user is a superuser.

Comment: The point of JWT are that they are self-contained, so as long as you have the public key to verify that the signature in the token is valid, you shouldn't have to contact service B at all?